# How to kill child process harmlessly

Tags: c, linux, race-condition

Parent process forks and gets child id. Child do some stuff. If it doesn't finish after 1 second parent kills it by id. But what if child has finished before 1 second elapsed and system executes another process with same id as my child had. In this case parent will kill innocent process. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PID is reserved until `wait` (or a similar function like `waitpid`) tells the parent that the process has exited.

If the process has exited but you the parent hasn't been told by `wait` yet, the process is called a "zombie". [Nothing happens when you kill a zombie process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256926/what-happends-when-sending-sigkill-to-a-zombie-process-in-linux).

So, your parent just needs to be careful to not send any signals after `wait` tells it that the child process finished. This should be easy. There is no race condition involved.

Note: This also means that you need to call `wait` (or a related function like `waitpid`) after spawning a child process. Alternatively, if your process exits, then zombie processes it created disappear (because they get "adopted" by PID 1, which calls `wait`).